# Запуск bat файла из PHP

Tags: php, apache, bat

Здравствуйте дорогие друзья, очередной вопрос из серии "ИЗВРАЩЕНИЕ". 
Можно ли (если да то каким образом) можно запустить внешний .bat файл из PHP. Собственно вызов внешнего файла не вызывает особых проблем а вот связка с внешним файлом то не могу этого понять. Хочу сделать так,  после вызова .bat файла если тот выполнился успешно то вывести на браузере что "всё хорошо" если нет то "Ошибка" , можно ли такое сделать средствами PHP или с вмешательством Apache

Хочу немного конкретизировать вопрос : есть BAT файл который снимает бекап БД , вот хочу внутри скрипта сделать кнопочку бекап и когда юзер нажимает на эту кнопку скрипт вызывает BAT , и в зависимости от того что бекапнул или нет выводит ответ в окне браузера

собственно бат :

```
@echo off 
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=someuser --password=somepass --result-
file="d:\bac\db.sql" dbname 
echo Sucess!
pause
exit
```

Comment: При этом нужно дожидаться окончания работы BAT-файла или нет?

Comment: думаю , чтоб узнать результат работы бат файла, всё таки нужно ждать окончание...есть какие то идеи ?

Comment: Перенаправить вывод в текстовый файл, затем распарсить?

Comment: хмм...можно и так

Comment: 1. Почему Sucess? во-первых тут опечатка, а во-вторых почему вы решили что если предыдущая команда завершилась, то она завершилась успешно? А если база в этот момент не работала? А если места/прав не хватило на бэкап?; 2. Если собираетесь запускать скрипт автоматически - уберите `pause`

Comment: А если воспользоваться string system ( string $command [, int &$return_var ] ), а в BAT-файле сделать перехват с записью в переменную, например, так: http://barbitoff.blogspot.ru/2011/09/bat.html

Answer (score 1):

Привет! Если тебе необходимо выполнить сторонний файл, ты можешь воспользоваться php функцией [exec](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php) . Если необходимо отследить состояние, то надо в самом батнике возвращать состояние завершения что бы ты мог понять "все хорошо" или "ошибка".

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Да все верно именно так и делаю. А вот хотелось бы отображать результат в самом браузере а не в "черном окне" bat а )

Comment: Смотри, в описании функции exec написано: return_var
Если заданы оба параметра return_var и output, то при выходе эта переменная будет содержать статус завершения внешней программы. После завершения батника ты можешь отследить его и уже делать то что хочешь

Comment: А можете подробнее ? и в ответ пожалуйста )

Comment: Тогда можно сразу запустить код из батника через exec. Тоесть `exec("C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=someuser --password=somepass --result-
file="d:\bac\db.sql" dbname");`